# Android Dark Theme does not affect SVG images

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable, android-dark-theme

My current Android application is employing the following style in an attempt to enable Dark Theme

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorError">@color/design_default_color_error</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorOnBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="splashDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Everything in the UI works fine apart from this SVG image which seems to be the same in both light and dark themes

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        android:pathData="M12,22c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2h-4c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2zM18,16v-5c0,-3.07 -1.63,-5.64 -4.5,-6.32L13.5,4c0,-0.83 -0.67,-1.5 -1.5,-1.5s-1.5,0.67 -1.5,1.5v0.68C7.64,5.36 6,7.92 6,11v5l-2,2v1h16v-1l-2,-2zM16,17L8,17v-6c0,-2.48 1.51,-4.5 4,-4.5s4,2.02 4,4.5v6z" />
</vector>
```

How can I achieve the desired result of a "lighter" image when in Dark mode?

Answer (score 1):

In my project I used negative filter for drawable, like this:

```
private val negative = floatArrayOf(
    -1.0f,     .0f,     .0f,    .0f, 255.0f, // red
    .0f,     -1.0f,     .0f,    .0f, 255.0f, // green
    .0f,       .0f,   -1.0f,    .0f, 255.0f, // blue
    .0f,       .0f,     .0f,   1.0f,   .0f  // alpha
)

fun Drawable.toNegative() {
    this.colorFilter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(negative)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply **gray-scale** as saturation, and reduce **alpha** as you want on the image view objects.

**Gray ImageView:**

```
imageView.colorFilter =
                ColorMatrixColorFilter(ColorMatrix().apply {
                    setSaturation(0f)
                })
```

**Reduce alpha:**

```
imageView.alpha = 0.5F
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this manually if all else fails:

1. Make a values-night folder
2. Copy/paste your colors.xml there
3. Edit the colors you want changed for dark mode
4. Edit the svg file for attributes

   `android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal" android:fillColor="@color/myFillColor"`

Sometimes you may need to make a separate night resource, for example I have an svg with an alpha value for day, but for night I don't want it. In that case you can either:

Make a drawable-night folder and create 2 separate svg's with the colors you wish.

OR

Use the same file, but copy/paste the dimens.xml file into the values-night folder.